# Can't determine my web host, need SSL certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, website, host, discovery

The person who created my website is long gone and I need to update the site and get a current SSL certificate.  The site has a Weebly logo on the home page, but I have no record of any old or ongoing payments to Weebly.  Our company email still uses Earthlink servers.  We pay them a monthly hosting fee, but the web site isn't on their servers. We're just paying for a very expensive email service, apparently.

How do I find and access the host and web server?  Site is mpicts.com, an http site registered with Register.com.

Answer (score 0):

According to the ip address that your website is using your host is on weebly.com and the reason you are not paying anything is maybe because you are using a free hosting plan. so just contact them and ask about it.

But aside that it is almost impossible to find the hosing company directly especially if the site is behind a CDN like cloudflare ( not your case ) ...